# Jstree JSON as Variable Java

Tags: java, jquery, json, jstree

I hav JSON data in the form of a string that I set as an attribute in my servlet.

```
    request.setAttribute("json", json);
```

I need to put this into a jstree from the jstl tag. I know I can't put the jstl straight into javascript so I did the following:

```
        <p id = "jsonPData">${json}</p>
```

In my javascript I have the following:

```
$(function () {
$("#jsonPData").hide();
var json = $("#jsonPData").text();

  $('#tree').jstree({ 'core' : {
        'data' : [
                  json
          ]
    } });

 });
```

When I don't hide the p element, the data is fine, and if I copy and paste it into the data section on jstree, it also works fine. However when I put the variable in for the jstree data, It puts it all into one node on the jstree. After looking at the code generated by the web browser, it seems that it is adding quotes around all the data in the json variable which would cause it to be only one node.

Any suggestions on how I should do this? Or another way?
Thanks!

Comment: var json = $.parseJSON(($("#jsonPData").text());

Comment: No that doesn't work either. Thanks though

Comment: Does console throwing any err?

Comment: <p id = "jsonPData">${json}</p> is this showing json content in html?

Comment: Thanks everyone but I got my answer, and no, console never threw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what ended up working. I had to remove the brackets in the 'data' area, and add eval(json) instead of just json.

```
$(function () {
    $('#jsonPData').hide();
    var json = $("#jsonPData").text();
      $('#tree').jstree({ 'core' : {
            'data' : eval(json)             
        } });     

  });
```